# Using stored procedure in MSTest DataSource (C#)

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datasource, mstest

Is there any way that a MSTest unit test can call a stored procedure in its `DataSource` attribute instead of just referencing a table in the connection string?

TIA

Comment: Does your procedure do any DML? If not, then it should be a `FUNCTION` which you could then invoke via a `VIEW` which you can query like any other base-table.

Comment: Not sure what a DML is? So far just looking to execute a simple SELECT statement.

Appreciate your response though, what would the code look like calling the view? Same connection string as with a table, except use a view name in place of table name?

If I can run a query in .Net inside my DataSource somehow this would also be an acceptable solution but I have not found a way to do this.

Comment: "DML" refers to statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `MERGE` - i.e. anything that writes changes to your DB, whereas queries using `SELECT` only perform read-only operations. In MS SQL Server, when you want to re-use a `SELECT` query it should be in a `FUNCTION` or a `VIEW` - and not a `PROCEDURE`. (Unfortunately there's _a lot_ of bad advice from nonexperts in content-farm-tier websites (like geeksforgeeks, w3schools, etc) which tell people to do the wrong thing (uggghhh) which causes confusion.

Comment: Ok sure but my question is how to call a function or a view from a datasource attribute in c#?

You can get datasource to come from a table using this syntax

[TestMethod]
[DataSource("Data Source=database-server;Initial Catalog=UnitTestData;Integrated Security=True;:")]

But what if I want it to come from a function for example?

Comment: The `tableName:` parameter for `DataSourceAttribute` can be the name of a `VIEW`, that's because tables and views are interchangable in SQL. And if you have a `FUNCTION` then you can wrap that in a new `VIEW` that supplies suitable arguments for the function's parameters.